# Using objects (that require a parameter) and their methods within another class

Tags: c++, beagleboneblack, robotics

I'm trying to program an omni directional robot with the BeagleBone Black. I've found the BlackLib library works realy well for controlling pins, but I'm having a little trouble integrating it into the larger scheme of things. If I simply create objects associated with pins and set them high or low (or somewhere in between) I am able to control the motor as desired. But when I try to create an object that contains BlackLib ojects, I run into difficulty. Seems to me, a good way to go about this would be to create a motor object that contains a GPIO and a PWM BlackLib object. Then I can create a function to easily set the power and direction with

```
rightMotor(50); //Should set the power to 50% in one direction
```

I've got some of it working, but am having trouble accessing the functions within the objects from BlackLib that are within my own Motors class.

Here's the code I'm working with now.

```
#include "BlackLib/BlackLib.h"

struct Motors
{
  BlackPWM* pwm;
  BlackGPIO* gpio;

  void drive(int power)
  {
    if(power >= 0)
    {
      gpio.setValue(low);
      //gpio.setValue(low); generates the error described below. I'm not familiar enough with the intricacies of pointers to know how to handle this
      //motors.cpp: In member function ‘void Motors::drive(int)’:
      //motors.cpp:15:10: error: request for member ‘setValue’ in ‘((Motors*)this)->Motors::gpio’, which is of non-class type ‘BlackGPIO*’
//      pwm.setDutyPercent(power);
    }
    else
    {
//      gpio.setValue(high);
//      pwm.setDutyPercent(100+power);
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
  struct Motors rightMotor;
  rightMotor.pwm = new BlackPWM(P9_16);
  rightMotor.gpio = new BlackGPIO(GPIO_49,output);

  //Give the BeagleBone a little time to create the objects
  usleep(10000);

  rightMotor.pwm.setPeriodTime(500000);
  //I will eventually need to set the period time but I'm not sure how. I'm guessing this is the incorrect syntax
  //Ideally, I would create a function so that I could simply write rightMotor.setPeriodTime(500000);

  rightMotor.drive(50);
  sleep(1);
  rightMotor.drive(0);
}
```

If I'm totally off base and there's a much better way to do this, please let me know. My end goal is to be able to easily control multiple motors. Eventually I would like to create functions and classes such as

```
robot.turn(30);
```

or

```
robot.forward(100);
```

Comment: What is your experience with C++? You're doing some basic mistakes here (like accessing a member function of a pointer via `.` instead of `->`, or bad encapsulation). I'd strongly recommend to get some introduction for C++/OOP before tackling such a project.

Answer (score 0):

Got the following solution from a professor of computer science at the University of Alaska Fairbanks. Works as desired now.

```
struct Motors
{
        BlackPWM pwm;
        BlackGPIO gpio;

        Motors(pwm_pin_name pwmPin,gpio_name gpioPin) //motor constructor parameters
                : pwm(pwmPin),gpio(gpioPin,output) //member initializer list
        {
                pwm.setPeriodTime(500000);
        }

        void drive(int power)
        {
                if(power >= 0)
                {
                        gpio.setValue(low);
                        pwm.setDutyPercent(power);
                }
                else
                {
                        gpio.setValue(high);
                        pwm.setDutyPercent(100+power);
                }
        }
};

int main()
{
        //User interface pins
        BlackGPIO button(GPIO_44,input);

        Motors rightMotor(P9_16,GPIO_49);

        while(!button.isHigh())
        {
                rightMotor.drive(0);
        }

        //The BeagleBone needs a little time to create the PWM object
        usleep(10000);

        rightMotor.drive(-50);

        sleep(1);

        rightMotor.drive(0);
}
```